# The text is not displaying but the speech is working

Tags: html, ajax, text, display

I am having a problem with displaying the serving list from AJAX every 1 second. The speech is working but the display text is not. Here's my code: I want it to be viewable like Cashier Name and Customer Name, the code is perfectly fine at first, but it is now not working after I added the speech and row.notify statement

HTML Code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <center><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary w-25" id="start" type="button">Start Live Queue Monitor</button></center>
    <div class="border-dark border-3 border shadow d-none" id="monitor-holder">
        <div class="row my-0 mx-0">
            <div class="col-md-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center border-end border-dark" id="serving-field">

                <div class="card col-sm-12 shadow h-100">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Now Serving</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body h-100">
                        <div class="card-body h-100">
                            <div id="serving-list" class="list-group overflow-auto">
                                <?php
                                $cashier = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `cashier_list` order by `name` asc");
                                while ($row = $cashier->fetchArray()) :
                                ?>
                                    <div class="list-group-item" data-id="<?php echo $row['cashier_id'] ?>" style="display:none">
                                        <div class="fs-5 fw-2 cashier-name border-bottom border-info"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></div>
                                        <div class="ps-4"><span class="serve-queue fs-4 fw-bold">1001 - John Smith</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center bg-dark bg-gradient text-light" id="action-field">
                <div class="col-auto flex-grow-1">
                    <?php
                    $vid = scandir('./../../video');
                    $video = isset($vid[2]) ? $vid[2] : "";
                    ?>
                    <video id="loop-vid" src="./../../video/<?php echo $video ?>" loop class="w-100 h-100"></video>
                </div>
                <div id="datetimefield" class="w-100  col-auto">
                    <div class="fs-1 text-center time fw-bold"></div>
                    <div class="fs-5 text-center date fw-bold"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    let tts = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    tts.lang = "en";
    tts.voice = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()[0];
    let notif_audio = new Audio("./../../audio/ascend.mp3")
    let vid_loop = $('#loop-vid')[0]
    tts.onstart = () => {
        vid_loop.pause()
    }
    notif_audio.setAttribute('muted', true)
    notif_audio.setAttribute('autoplay', true)
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(notif_audio)

    function speak($text = "") {
        if ($text == '')
            return false;
        tts.text = $text;
        notif_audio.setAttribute('muted', false)
        notif_audio.play()
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(tts);
            tts.onend = () => {
                vid_loop.play()
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    function time_loop() {
        var hour, min, ampm, mo, d, yr, s;
        let mos = ['', 'January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
        var datetime = new Date();
        hour = datetime.getHours()
        min = datetime.getMinutes()
        s = datetime.getSeconds()
        hour12 = hour >= 12 ? hour - 12 : hour;
        hour12 = hour12 == 0 ? 12 : hour12;
        ampm = hour >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
        mo = mos[datetime.getMonth()]
        d = datetime.getDay()
        yr = datetime.getFullYear()
        hour = hour >= 12 ? hour - 12 : hour;
        hour = String(hour).padStart(2, 0)
        min = String(min).padStart(2, 0)
        s = String(s).padStart(2, 0)
        $('.time').text(hour12 + ":" + min + ":" + s + " " + ampm)
        $('.date').text(mo + " " + d + ", " + yr)


    }

    function _resize_elements() {
        var window_height = $(window).height()
        var nav_height = $('nav').height()
        var container_height = window_height - nav_height
        $('#serving-field,#action-field').height(container_height - 50)
        $('#serving-list').height($('#serving-list').parent().height() - 30)
    }

    function new_queue() {
        // Make an AJAX call to fetch the data from the server
        $.ajax({
            url: './../../Actions.php?a=cashier_get_queue_backup',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            error: err => console.log(err),
            success: function(resp) {
                if (resp.status == 'success') {
                    $.each(resp.data, function(i, row) {
                        var item = $('#serving-list').find('.list-group-item[data-id="' + row.cashier_id + '"]');
                        var cashier = item.find('.cashier-name').text();
                        var nitem = item.clone();
                        if (row.priority == 1) {
                            nitem.find('.serve-queue').text(row.customer_name + " ♿");
                        } else {
                            nitem.find('.serve-queue').text(row.customer_name);
                        }
                        item.remove();
                        $('#serving-list').prepend(nitem);
                        if (row.queue == '') {
                            nitem.hide('slow');
                        } else {
                            nitem.show('slow');
                        }
                        if (row.notify == 1) {
                         speak("Calling the attention of " + row.customer_name + ", Please proceed to " + row.name);
                        } else {}
                    });
                }
            }

        });
    }

    $(function() {
        setInterval(() => {
            time_loop()
            new_queue()
        }, 1000);
        $('#start').click(function() {
            $(this).hide()
            $('#monitor-holder').removeClass('d-none')
            _resize_elements()
            vid_loop.play()
        })
        $(window).resize(function() {
            _resize_elements()
        })
    })
</script>
```

Actions in backend AJAX

```
    function cashier_get_queue_backup()
    { // for cashier monitoring backup
        extract($_POST);
        $qry = $this->query("SELECT cql.*, cl.name FROM cashier_queue_list cql LEFT JOIN cashier_list cl ON cql.cashier_id = cl.cashier_id WHERE cql.status = 1 ORDER BY cql.queue_id ASC");
        $resp['status'] = 'success';
        $resp['data'] = array(); // initialize an empty array to hold the rows
        while ($row = $qry->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
            $row['customer_name'] = openssl_decrypt($row['customer_name'], "DES-ECB", "902e2ijio2jklqd");
            array_push($resp['data'], $row); // add the modified row to the array
        }
        if (empty($resp['data'])) {
            $resp['data'] = array(); // set an empty array if no rows are found
        }
        $qry2 = $this->query("UPDATE cashier_queue_list SET notify = 0");
        return json_encode($resp);
    }
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a ***[mcve]*** of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You should never loop AJAX. Instead call again with a timeout in the success

Comment: Note that the `<center>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for 15 years or more.